# Symlink to file within same NPM module

Tags: github, npm, symlink

In a GitHub module, it is possible to symlink to another file within the same module. But is it possible to have this symlink survive / work in the NPM package of same module?

I'm using a Mac and so far I've done

```
ln -s [filename-1.0.4.js] [filename.js]
```

This works great for github.io-pages, but the file disappears when published to NPM.

Comment: Doesn't look like it, only `npm link` for external folders seems to be a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some rounds with NPM support it seems that only folders can be linked with `npm link`

So the answer to my question is no. Here's the [documentation for npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html)

And here is the answer from support:

[...]

To create a symlink in a package.json, we recommend using the scripts field.

For example:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm link ../somelocallib",
    "postupdate": "npm link ../somelocallib"
  }
```

[...]